# tclientdataset's delta property

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

do any one know the how to clear the data in the delta of the TclientDataSet explicitly? without using applyupdates

thanks in advance,
Vijay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cancel all updates without applying them, call CancelUpdates.

Comment: @Vijay: Yeah, it happens.  Even experienced coders sometimes overlook something obvious.  Welcome to StackOverflow!  Hopefully you can find some good answers here, and give some answers to other people's questions as well. :)